# CI/CD Pipeline Azure Devops - removed folder permissons

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

Every time I publish my project my folder permissons get removed. My project requires IIS APPPOOL\appPoolName and IUSR to have specific access right to specific folders.
Whats the best way to apply the folder permissons after the artifact has been published?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if totally get your point. You can use location elements in the web.config file, there is a lot of information on the web about that - this gives you a start:  [HOW TO: Control Authorization Permissions in an ASP.NET Application](http://sedodream.com/2011/11/08/settingfolderpermissionsonwebpublish.aspx)

Besides, for folder NTFS permissions here rather than web security permissions. You could also add a custom target to Visual Studio's web publishing pipeline. For detail ways please take a look at what *Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi* does [here](http://sedodream.com/2011/11/08/settingfolderpermissionsonwebpublish.aspx).

Comment: Hi ended up going down a slightly different route. I saw that you can use powershell as part of the release pipeline. I found a powershell script here https://thesitedoctor.co.uk/blog/how-to-quickly-set-umbraco-file-and-folder-permissions-with-powershell/ which I modified for umbraco 8. But thank you so much for coming back to me.

Comment: Hi Lori, Thanks for the update.Glad to hear this. You could also share the solution here as an answer and mark it. Which will also help others in the community in case they get stuck with same issue as you.